# How multiple recursion on same function works

Tags: java, recursion

Can someone explain how the flow of this recursion executing one after another works for function powerset

```
static void powerSet(String str, int index, 
            String curr) 

{ 
    int n = str.length(); 
    if (index == n)
    { 
        System.out.println(curr);
        return; 
    } 
    powerSet(str, index + 1, curr + str.charAt(index)); 
    powerSet(str, index + 1, curr);
} 

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String str = "abc"; 
        int index = 0;
        String curr="";
    powerSet(str,index,curr); 

    }
}
```

I have gone through multiple links but unable to understand

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint and stepped through the code line by line?

Comment: Till now I have worked with single recursive functions, I am not able to understand whether they execute together or one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is asynchronous here, so the program will wait each call to be finished before it goes to the next instruction. Meaning that as long as it has not returned from the first inner call of powerSet, the second will not fire. Of course there is an implicit return from each function after the second inner call is finished

Here are the steps followed manually; I've called `powerSet1` the first inner recursive call and `powerSet2` the second one:

```
main call: powerSet("abc", 0, "");
    powerSet1("abc", 1, "a");
        powerSet1("abc", 2, "ab");
            powerSet1("abc", 3, "abc");
                3===3 => print "abc" and return
            powerSet2("abc", 3, "ab");
                3===3 => print "ab" and return
        powerSet2("abc", 2, "a");
            powerSet1("abc", 3, "ac");
                3===3 => print "ac" and return
            powerSet2("abc", 3, "a");
                3===3 => print "a" and return
    powerSet2("abc", 1, "");
        powerSet1("abc", 2, "b");
            powerSet1("abc", 3, "bc");
                3===3 => print "bc" and return
            powerSet2("abc", 3, "b");
                3===3 => print "b" and return
        powerSet2("abc", 2, "");
            powerSet1("abc", 3, "c");
                3===3 => print "c" and return
            powerSet2("abc", 3, "");
                3===3 => print "" and return
```

The result is then the following (with an empty string at the end):

```
abc
ab
ac
a
bc
b
c
```

EDIT: here is a more detailled version: keep in mind that each indentation is a new function called that keeps its values for `index` and `curr`, I have left vertical dashed lines so you can easily find what were the values for this level. The program follows the solid line:

```
NOTE: for all recursion levels str="abc" (stays unchanged)

main call: powerSet("abc", 0, "");
 index=0 / curr=""
 |
 └-- powerSet1("abc", 1, "a");
     index=1 / curr="a"
 |   |
     └-- powerSet1("abc", 2, "ab");
 |       index=2 / curr="ab"
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet1("abc", 3, "abc");
     |       index=3 / curr="abc"
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "abc" and return -┐
 |       ┌----------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet2("abc", 3, "ab");
     |       index=3 / curr="ab"
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "ab" and return -┐
 |       ┌---------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- end of function (implicit return) -┐
     ┌------------------------------------------┘
 |   |
     └-- powerSet2("abc", 2, "a");
 |       index=2 / curr="a"
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet1("abc", 3, "ac");
     |       index=3 / curr="ac"
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "ac" and return -┐
 |       ┌---------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet2("abc", 3, "a");
     |       index=3 / curr="a"
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "a" and return -┐
 |       ┌--------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- end of function (implicit return) -┐
     ┌------------------------------------------┘
 |   |
     └-- end of function (implicit return) -┐
 ┌------------------------------------------┘
 |
 └-- powerSet2("abc", 1, "");
     index=1 / curr=""
 |   |
     └-- powerSet1("abc", 2, "b");
 |       index=2 / curr="b"
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet1("abc", 3, "bc");
     |       index=3 / curr="bc"
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "bc" and return -┐
 |       ┌---------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet2("abc", 3, "b");
     |       index=3 / curr="b"
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "b" and return -┐
 |       ┌--------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- end of function (implicit return) -┐
     ┌------------------------------------------┘
 |   |
     └-- powerSet2("abc", 2, "");
 |       index=2 / curr=""
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet1("abc", 3, "c");
     |       index=3 / curr="c"
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "c" and return -┐
 |       ┌--------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- powerSet2("abc", 3, "");
     |       index=3 / curr=""
 |       |   |
     |       └-- index==str.length => print "" and return -┐
 |       ┌-------------------------------------------------┘
     |   |
 |       └-- end of function (implicit return) -┐
     |<-----------------------------------------┘
 |   |
     └-- end of function (implicit return) -┐
 |<-----------------------------------------┘
 |
 └-- end of function (final return)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much 
At line 6 where I am returning ABC and going to powerset2, why is the value of index still 3 and value of curr = "AB"

Comment: @joshua both inner calls use `index + 1` without changing the value of `index`, so they call it with the same value. So that you'll notice that for each indentation (level of recursion) it's always the same index. For `curr` the second inner call (`powerset2`) adds nothing and passes it unchanged. On line 6 the value received for `curr` was `"ab"` (the call at line 3) so it is passed without change

Comment: When arguments of powerset 1 is (abc,3,abc) than it goes to main function powerset(abc,3,abc) so after abc is printed and returned to powerset 2 it should have argument(abc,4,abc)

Comment: No, what is noticeable here is that nothing is ever returned from the nested recursions. You can see in the `powerSet` function that no variable is ever changed between the calls, and the result of the calls are not stored. It then can never reach 4 because of the `if (index == n)` test. When the received index is equal to the string length, the `return` exits the function and the inner calls are not fired.

Comment: Why index+1 not changes value of 3 to 4 when powerset 2 is executing

Comment: @joshua because index is not changed between the call of powerset 1 and powerset 2. Each function call remembers what were it's own values when the program returns to them, those values are not shared between the recursion levels. I've made a more detailled diagram, keep in mind that for each vertical indentation a set of local variables are created and they don't change